# How can I serialize a Java object to a escaped JSON string?

Tags: java, json

Is there a way to convert a Java object to a string like below?
Note that all the filed names should be escaped, and `"\n"` is used as to separate records.

```
{

"content":"{\"field1\":123, \"field2\":1, \"field3\":0, \"field4\":{\"sub1\":\"abc\", \"sub2\":\"xyz\"}}\n
{\"field1\":234, \"field2\":9, \"field3\":1, \"field4\":{\"sub1\":\"xyz\", \"sub2\":\"abc\"}}"

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: For example of JSON libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for that task.

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.

If you need to have a better readable representation, you may use the pretty-print feature.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

To realize something like your example, you could in a first step serialize your content class, put the resulting string as a property in another class and serialize that one again.

That way GSON takes care of the escaping of `"`.

If you collect your strings in an array and use the pretty print option shown above, you get something similar to your line-break requirement, but not quite the exact same.

The result of the process described above may look like the following:

```
{
  "content": [ 
    "{\"field1\":123, \"field2\":1, \"field3\":0, \"field4\":{\"sub1\":\"abc\", \"sub2\":\"xyz\"}}",
    "{\"field1\":234, \"field2\":9, \"field3\":1, \"field4\":{\"sub1\":\"xyz\", \"sub2\":\"abc\"}}"
  ]
}
```

Comment: And for the strange escaping requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the Json-lib library [http://json-lib.sourceforge.net](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)

```
String jsonStrData = " ....... ";
JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonStrData);
System.out.println(jsonObj);
```

Like GSON, json-lib handles escaping for you, more info on how to use it here http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html